# Failed to open VM attachment when Hyper-V Node reboots

Tags: hyper-v

We run a cluster with Hyper-V. On every reboot, the cluster throws the error
Alarm:  Failed to open VM attachment
Details:    Fired by event: 12240 Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS
Event description: "": Die Anlage "C:\CLUSTERSTORAGE\VOLUME01\HYPER-V\HV3_BITRIX\VIRTUAL HARD DISKS\BITRIX.VHDX" wurde nicht gefunden. Fehler: "Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden." (0x80070003) (ID des virtuellen Computers ).
Initiated by: NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM

The file cannot be found because the VM does not exist anymore. How can I fix this?

Regards,
Thomas